# How to make Battery Saver Mode settings permanent?

Tags: settings, battery, google-play-services, 8.1-oreo

And I have set my Battery Saver Mode settings as follows:

```
$ adb shell
$ su
# settings put global battery_saver_constants "animation_disabled=true,vibration_disabled=true,adjust_brightness_disabled=true"
# cat /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml | grep '"battery_saver_constants"'
  <setting id="528" name="battery_saver_constants" value="animation_disabled=true,vibration_disabled=true,adjust_brightness_disabled=true" package="root" />
```

Unfortunately at some point those settings are being reset.

```
# cat /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml | grep '"battery_saver_constants"'
  <setting id="533" name="battery_saver_constants" package="com.google.android.gms" />
```

It seems that the app "com.google.android.gms" is overriding my settings.

I have disabled the "Modify system settings" for this app but this does not help.

I am using Android 8.1, OxygenOS 5.1.9.

Comment: Does that "overwriting" happen at some special event (I have reboot in mind here especially), or rather at a random time?

Comment: It seems like a random, one time it took whole day and other time it took less than two hours. But I do not think it is in fact random, yet I don't know the cause.